# I'm using one table in a mysql database. I want duplicate entries in some fields

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm setting this up in phpmyadmin.  It's a simple table listing a collection of films.  One column records the year the film was made.  Another the decade it was made. A third, the genre.

I'm getting this message from phpmyadmin:

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '30' for key 'decade'

This is on the second insert. But,  this will also happen for genre and eventually for year.

I thought at first that making these fields varchar instead of int would solve the problem, but I guess I just don't have the colums set up correctly.

What do I need to do?

My Schema:

`MariaDB [movies]> desc films;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| alpha-name | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| page-link  | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| sm-pic     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| year       | varchar(4)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| decade     | varchar(2)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| genre      | varchar(10)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

I see now that the keys are designated UNI, but where in phpmyadmin do I select it so that I can allow duplicates?

I can't see where I can thank people so I'm doing it here...

dropping the indexes on these fields does seem to have worked. Thanks for the specific code.

Comment: Add your table schema but I suspect that `decade` has been set as a _primary_ or _unique_ key.

Comment: Drop your indexes ... insert your data ... then work out the correct indexes that you want.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Alter films drop index <column_name>
```